# Mathematical Formulation for Accelerating Charges Generating Light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, particle-accelerators

I haven't been formally taught the fact that accelerating charges generate light, and I have seen the picture of an accelerating charge sending ripples down its field lines, but is there a mathematical formulation someone can provide that show that an acceleration on a charge produces E&M waves?

Comment: Jackson, *Classical Electrodynamics*. Chapter 14, starting on p. 661 in the third edition.

Answer (score 0):

The radiation from an accelerating charge in the non-relativistic regime is described by the [Larmour equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula). The extension to relativistic speeds is given by the [Liénard–Wiechert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential) equation.